# Keep a program running in terminal

Tags: bash, gnome, background-process, nohup

So I am well aware of `nohup` and suffixing commands with `&` to ensure that they go into the background.

However if I run a graphical application - sometimes using neither seems to do the job. So what can I prefix a  program/command with to ensure that it keeps running after the terminal is closed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the application to keep running when you close the terminal window you should do:

```
nohup chromium-browser &
```

You need both the `nohup` and the `&`.

- nohup means keep this process/command running after the shell closes.
- & means put this process/command in the background so it dose not block the shell (so you can use it for something else.

Answer (score 5):

when running a program in the background via the & operator it's still attached to your session and can be controlled with fg, bg, jobs and disown.

I also had some problems with nohup but disown might be the thing you're looking for.

When you run a program in background it has a job id:

```
gedit &
[1] 5647
```

That number in brackets [] is the interesting one. To detatch it from your session run `disown %n` with that number. For the above example:

```
disown %1
```

Now you can safely exit the terminal and the process will not be terminated.

Answer (score 2):

For graphical applications, simply doing something like this should work (at least, it does for me)

`chromium-browser&`

For terminal applications, you should use something like `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: -1 as this won't work for the requirement to keep running after terminal is closed. +1 for suggesting screen/tmux.

Comment: @gertvdijk interesting, for GUI applications it works for me. Just tested using bash. I have had instances where zsh will complain if I do that and then try to exit...

Comment: I was using Konsole and running Kate in it with `&` appended. Kate will close subsequently after closing Konsole.

Answer (score -1):

Close the terminal, from which you started the graphical program, with

```
exit
```

Comment: A comment on the downvote might be helpful.