# How can I keep vpn running even after exiting terminal?

Tags: networking, command-line, vpn

I have a program that runs on Ubuntu (14.04) whether I am in the terminal or not. This program relies on a vpn connection, for which I am using vpnc (cisco).

I have added vpnc to my reboot and start up processes, and my program works fine when I reboot (and soon thereafter log in to the terminal). But when I exit the terminal, I lose the vpn connection and the program throws an exception.

Can anyone help me figure out how to keep the vpn connection running even after I log out of the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start vpnc using [nohup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/nohup.1.html). See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97131/keep-a-program-running-in-terminal) question.

For example to start `command` and to redirect its output to `command.log` use:

```
nohup command > command.log &
```

If you want to see the output use:

```
tail -f command.log
```

Comment: @user3079064 Thanks for the help, but for some reason this solution is not working with vpnc. The vpn keeps going down as soon as I exit the terminal.

Comment: have you tried `nohup /usr/sbin/vpnc config.conf &`?

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. I am using `sudo nohup vpnc &` (and my config file is in a place that vpnc regularly checks). `sudo vpnc` works fine whenever I am logged into putty (even if I log back in later) but never when I am outside putty.

Comment: What about `nohup sudo vpnc &`?

Comment: Thanks again for the guidance, but that also produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Byobu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu):

> **Byobu** is a light, powerful, text-based window manager based on GNU Screen . Using Byobu, you can quickly create and move between
> different windows over a single SSH connection or TTY terminal,
> monitor dozens of important statistics about your system, detach and
> reattach to sessions later while your programs continue to run in the
> background.

Just open byobu

```
byobu
```

In this new terminal start vpnc or what you need

press <kbd>F6</kbd> to detach from this session

If you need this session you just need to run byobu again with

```
byobu
```

This session will "survive" your logout :)

For more shortcuts see the link in the first line...

**IMPORTANT**:

Don't forget that if you want this session to stay active you must leave the session with <kbd>F6</kbd>